# The name doesn't exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Help! I can't do data binding properly on my Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT app.

Here's my App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Neomilano.App" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="using:Neomilano">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionary.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Dictionary.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Neomilano"
xmlns:conv="using:Neomilano.Converters"
xmlns:vm="using:Neomilano.ViewModels">

<x:String x:Key="ApplicationName">Neomilano</x:String>

<!--converters available in Neomilano.Converters-->
<conv:StringToLowerConverter x:Key="StringToLowerConverter" />
<conv:StringToUpperConverter x:Key="StringToUpperConverter" />

<vm:TermsViewModel x:Key="TermsVM" />
```

TermsViewModel.cs located in a ViewModels folder:

```
using Neomilano.Model;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Neomilano.ViewModels
{
    public class TermsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Term> terms;
        public ObservableCollection<Term> Terms {
            get { return this.terms; }
            private set
            {
                if (terms != value)
                {
                    terms = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Terms");
                }
            }
        }

        public TermsViewModel()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the list of Terms from the database and adds it to the Terms property of the ViewModel.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task GetTermsList()
        {
            //var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(app.DBPath);
            //var list = await db.Table<Term>().ToListAsync();

            //terms = new ObservableCollection<Term>(list);
            List<Term> list = new List<Term>();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var db = new SQLiteConnection(app.DBPath);
                list = db.Table<Term>().ToList<Term>();

            });

            Terms = new ObservableCollection<Term>(list);

            Debug.WriteLine("Check terms now");
        }
    }
}
```

The error showing up on my error list is: `The name "TermsViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "using:Neomilano.ViewModels".`

To note, I am using Tim Heuer's private build of SQLite for WP 8.1. Already tried restarting Visual Studio, but it's no good.

**UPDATE:** I tried placing my pages, which are under the `Neomilano` namespace, as static resources. No problems there, so I tried to move out the ViewModels out of the `Neomilano.ViewModels` namespace, while remaining on their folder structure in the project. The pages remain to be free from errors, but the ViewModels, together with the Models (they also have their own folder), doesn't work and gets the same error.

**UPDATE:** I discovered something that is probably linked to this issue. [I posted it on a separate submission.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495601/cannot-find-assembly-at-design-time-in-visual-studio)

More details to be provided if needed.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Have you tried to clean and build your project?

Comment: Yep. Didn't work too.

Comment: Try deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders. Also, while I have gotten this error before that did not prevent me from running the app just fine. Are there any other warnings?

Comment: Didn't work. It does build fine, though; just can't see the key of the ViewModel in Intellisense. No other warnings.

Comment: @RaffyAlcoriza Does that mean '*builds fine*' that your App works fine, and the problem is with Intellisense?

Comment: I mean it compiles and runs on the device. I just can't figure out how can I data bind it while coding when the key does not show up in the Intellisense or in the properties editor (or whatever you call that thing that comes from the context menu on Properties).

Comment: Updated the main post with some more discoveries.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close VS.
2. Delete all (hidden) SUO files - there may be 2.
3. Rerun VS. Ghost errors should be gone.

Comment: Nope, didn't work too. I discovered something that may be related to this issue. See the update on the post.

Comment: it gives "page not found"